# React Router Authentication Async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-router

I'm new to react.

I want to add some security to my Async-Routes which I implemented in my routes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './app.jsx';
import Home from './components/home.jsx';

import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router';

function loadRoute(cb) {
  return (module) => cb(null, module.default);
}

const routes = {
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: "/hello/:foo",
            getComponent(location, cb) {
                System.import('./components/hello.jsx')
                  .then(loadRoute(cb))
                  .catch(errorLoading);
              }
        },
    ]
};

export default () => <Router history={hashHistory} routes={routes} />
```

As you can see the "/hello/:foo" route is async.

How can I restrict the access to this route (role-based) and redirect to somewhere else (e.g. login)?

I want to load the chunk only when it's needed.

Should I place the checking code into "getComponent()"?

Can it be done with "willTransitionTo()", will this function be executed before "getComponent()" and how should I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I would place the checking code into componentWillMount(), and in render() return the page component, or display/redirect to login.

If you have multiple page that need access restricted, I'd create a high level component order for each page component to check access before rendering.